A grey border is showing in Html code in Flutter WebView
I'm using WebView to display an vision360 video in flutter. The URL was not looking right in WebView that why JavaScript is used to modify width and height of video and buttons, But in some big devices a grey line is coming along with video. Here is the JavaScript. In Device greater or equal to 6.7 inch the grey line is visible
<html style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; display:flex; justify-content:center;">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.98">
  </head>
  <body style="width:95%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; ">
    <div style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;">
      <iframe src="https://storageweweb.blob.core.windows.net/files/INVENTORYDATA/V360Mini5/Vision360.html?d=790364830-S&autoPlay=1&z=0"
        style="width:100%; height:100%; border:none;"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

This is Flutter WebView code
class HtmlWebViewInterface extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  final bool isB2bSparkle;
  final bool isSmallerView;
  final void Function(double)? onScaleChanged;
  String? type;

  HtmlWebViewInterface({
    super.key,
    required this.url,
    this.isSmallerView = false,
    this.isB2bSparkle = false,
    this.onScaleChanged,
    this.type = 'medium',
  });

  @override
  State<HtmlWebViewInterface> createState() => HtmlWebViewInterfaceState();
}

class HtmlWebViewInterfaceState extends State<HtmlWebViewInterface> {
  final ValueNotifier<double> _progressValueNotifier = ValueNotifier<double>(0);

  // Ranges from 0 to 1.
  late final WebViewController _webViewController = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..loadHtmlString(widget.isSmallerView
        ? getHtmlString(widget.url,type: widget.type)
        : getHtmlStringForSmallView(widget.url, type: widget.type))
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) {
          _progressValueNotifier.value = progress / 100;
        },
        onPageFinished: (_) {
          _progressValueNotifier.value = 1;
        },
      ),
    );
   // ..setBackgroundColor(Colors.red);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            child: WebViewWidget(
              controller: _webViewController,
              gestureRecognizers: {
                Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                  () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                ),
              },
            ),
          ),
          Positioned.fill(
            child: ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: _progressValueNotifier,
              builder: (context, value, _) {
                if (value < 1) {
                  return widget.isB2bSparkle
                      ? buildProgressIndicator(context,
                          name: 'Loading B2B Sparkle Video...', showName: true)
                      : buildProgressIndicator(context,
                          name: 'Loading Video...', showName: true);
                } else {
                  return const SizedBox();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void reloadWebView() {
    _webViewController.reload();
  }
}

I tried providing border none in html code but nothing is working,
I need video should come with without grey line in big devices

